# Thorntail - WildFly Elytron Security remote connection getting authentication failed: none of the mechanisms presented by the server are supported

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0, thorntail, elytron, wildfly-18

I have configured WildFly Elytron Security on thorntail application using project-defaults.yml. However the application is failing to invoke or connect to the remote secured EJB's

Here is the yaml configuration for Elytron - Am not sure if this is correctly configured.

```
thorntail:
  elytron:
    sasl-authentication-factories:
      application-sasl-authentication:
        mechanism-configurations:
          - mechanism-name: 'GSSAPI'
          - mechanism-name: 'PLAIN'
          - mechanism-name: 'JBOSS-LOCAL-USER'
          - mechanism-name: 'DIGEST-MD5'
          - mechanism-realm-configurations:
              - realm-name: ApplicationRealm
        security-domain: ApplicationDomain
        sasl-server-factory: configured
    authentication-configurations:
      default:
        security-domain: ApplicationDomain
        sasl-mechanism-selector: 'PLAIN'
    security-domains:
      ApplicationDomain:
        realms:
          - realm: ApplicationRealm
        default-realm: ApplicationRealm

  remoting:
    http-connectors:
      http-remoting-connector:
        sasl-security:
          policy-sasl-policy:
            no-plain-text: false
          include-mechanisms:
            - 'PLAIN'
        sasl-authentication-factory: application-sasl-authentication
        security-realm: ApplicationRealm
        connector-ref: default

  management:
    https:
      port: 9993
    http:
      port: 9990
    security-realms:
      ApplicationRealm:
        jaas-authentication:
          name: AppSecDom
        ssl-server-identity:
          alias: 'alias'
          keystore-provider: PKCS12
          keystore-path: ${javax.net.ssl.keyStore}
          keystore-password: ${javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword}
```

From the client side this is how i try to connect to the EJB.

```
    public final static AuthenticationContext authenticationContext() throws  Exception{
        LOG.info("***********Start AUTHENTICATION*****************." );
        try{
            AuthenticationConfiguration config = AuthenticationConfiguration.empty().setSaslMechanismSelector(SaslMechanismSelector.NONE.addMechanism("#ALL")).
                    useName("username").usePassword("password");
            final AuthenticationContext authCtx = AuthenticationContext.empty().
                    with(MatchRule.ALL, config);
            ContextManager<AuthenticationContext> contextManager = authCtx.getInstanceContextManager();
            contextManager.setThreadDefault(authCtx);
            return contextManager.get();
        }catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error("Error authentication : " + e);
            throw  new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Error from the console.

```
Suppressed: org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: Destination @ remote+http://127.0.0.1:8080
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.handleFailed(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:104)
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.handleFailed(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:76)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
    Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: none of the mechanisms presented by the server (GSSAPI, JBOSS-LOCAL-USER, GS2-KRB5-PLUS, GS2-KRB5, ANONYMOUS) are supported
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:444)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:242)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
        at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
```

Please assist with this issue as am not sure what i need to do next.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm no Elytron expert, and I can't see anything wrong here. Do you have a similar configuration working with WildFly? That's where I would start -- get it running with WildFly, and then translate to Thorntail.

Comment: @Ladicek Thanks for pointing me into a right direction. It is now working. However it would be nice if you can add another example for Wildfly Elytron along with this ones https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples

Answer (score 0):

The below yaml configuration worked.

```
thorntail:
  elytron:
    simple-role-decoders:
      from-roles-attribute:
        attribute: roles
    jdbc-realms:
      app-jdbc-realm:
        principal-query:
          - sql: SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME  = ?
            data-source: TestDS
            clear-password-mapper:
              password-index: 1
          - sql: SELECT R.NAME, 'Roles' FROM USERS_ROLES UR INNER JOIN ROLES R ON R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID INNER JOIN USERS U ON U.ID = UR.USER_ID WHERE U.USERNAME = ?
            data-source: TestDS
            attribute-mapping:
              - index: 1
                to: roles

    sasl-authentication-factories:
      application-sasl-authentication:
        mechanism-configurations:
          - mechanism-name: 'PLAIN'
          - mechanism-realm-configurations:
              - realm-name: app-jdbc-realm
        security-domain: ApplicationDomain
        sasl-server-factory: configured

    security-domains:
      ApplicationDomain:
        realms:
          - realm: app-jdbc-realm
            role-decoder: from-roles-attribute
        default-realm: app-jdbc-realm

  remoting:
    http-connectors:
      http-remoting-connector:
        sasl-authentication-factory: application-sasl-authentication
        security-realm: ApplicationRealm
        connector-ref: default
```

For more detailed explanation - including the sql script to create schema tables for user authentication details.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280474

https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples